# is it a good practice to pass an EF DbContext as delegate in services to attach all changes on it

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, design-patterns, dbcontext

Having the following context:

```
public class DemoContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionStringName = "DemoContext";
    public DemoContext() : base("name=DemoContext")
    {
        //_connectionStringName = "DemoContext";
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        //Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DemoContext, Migrations.Configuration>(_connectionStringName));
        Database.SetInitializer(new NullDatabaseInitializer<DemoContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

And this services:

```
public class EmployeeSvc
{
    private readonly DemoContext _context;

    public EmployeeSvc(Func<DemoContext> context)
    {
        _context = context();
    }

    public void Add(EmployeeAgg employee)
    {
        _context.Employees.Attach(new Employee()
        {
            Name = employee.Name,
            DateOfBirth = employee.DateOfBirth
        });
    }

    public void UpdateAll()
    {
        var employees = _context.Employees.ToList();
        foreach (var employee in employees)
        {
            employee.Name = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        }
    }
}

public class CompanySvc
{
    private readonly DemoContext _context;

    public CompanySvc(Func<DemoContext> context)
    {
        _context = context();
    }
    public void Add(CompanyAgg company)
    {
        _context.Companies.Attach(new Company()
        {
            CompanyName = company.CompanyName
        });
    }

    public void UpdateAll()
    {
        var empresas = _context.Companies.ToList();
        foreach (var empresa in empresas)
        {
            empresa.CompanyName = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        }
    }
}

public class EmployeeAgg
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyAgg
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Anf the following client code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new DemoContext();
        // ReSharper disable AccessToDisposedClosure
        var employeeSvc = new EmployeeSvc(() => context);
        var companySvc = new CompanySvc(() => context);
        // ReSharper restore AccessToDisposedClosure
        Console.WriteLine("Adding entities to context inside services");
        employeeSvc.Add(new EmployeeAgg()
        {
            DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10),
            Name = $"Employee name"
        });
        companySvc.Add(new CompanyAgg()
        {
            CompanyName = $"Company name"
        });

        employeeSvc.UpdateAll();
        companySvc.UpdateAll();
        context.SaveChanges();            
        context.Dispose();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Is it a good practice passing DbContext to application services as delegate in order to have a reference to a single instance and track all changes on it?

Comment: Yes, it is called Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's your example code, but there's no need here to use a delegate. You could as well just accept a `DbContext` and pass in the same instance:

```
public class EmployeeSvc
{
    private readonly DemoContext _context;
    public EmployeeSvc(DemoContext context)
    {
        _context = context();
    }
    // snip ...
}

public class CompanySvc
{
    private readonly DemoContext _context;
    public CompanySvc(DemoContext context)
    {
        _context = context();
    }
    // snip ...
}


 var context = new DemoContext();
 var employeeSvc = new EmployeeSvc(context);
 var companySvc = new CompanySvc(context);
```

This would give you the exact same result, without needing to pass in a delegate and immediately invoking it.

I suppose however that maybe your actual code is a bit more complicated. If so, you should look into `dependency injection` and a `DI`-container.

A DI-container allows you to manage your dependencies and their lifecycles. A common lifecycle is the `Singleton` lifecycle, where the container will always construct your dependencies passing in the same instance.

Comment: I did the test with those changes and it worked, when i added and entity with Add method it worked but when i user the Attached method it didnt work. So i need to check the methods to see how they behaive in diferrent scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to injection your dbContext is better to use interface.
func<> is not suitable.
in Dependency injection interface is suitable.
(excusme for bad english)

Comment: The inconvienience with EF is that if you create an Interface or an abstract class you cant use the Generating mapping views because it only works with classes that derived from DbContext. And i prefer to use EF only as infraestructure detail and create domain business classes. I dont do anemic domain models anymore [here](http://deviq.com/persistence-ignorance/)