# Can i Pass DbContext as interface or delegate

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am having two dbcontext so want to pass it though some function so I can switch between the two dbcontext or I have to change in all the api controller

```
  public class AccountClassesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly  ApplicationDbContext _context;


    public AccountClassesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/AccountClasses
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AccountClass>>> GetAccountClass()
    {
        return await _context.AccountClass.ToListAsync();
    }
```

don't want to call the ApplicationDbContext from controller call it through some function or something

I have implemented database connection for postgresql and sqlserver now for them each one creates a different type of migration in code first, so had to create two dbcontext, now I want to be able to switch between dbcontext when I using postgresql or sql server

Comment: using some repository pattern and abstract the data access layer is possible. your controller even shouldn't depend on any dbcontext.

Comment: can you provide with an example I am new to this or doc

Comment: [eShopOnWeb](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) is an example, and you can find many documents about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create interfaces and modify your ApplicationDbContext to implement.

interface

```cs
public interface IAccountClass {
    Task<IEnumerable<AccountClass>> GetAccountClass();
}
```

```cs
public class AppDbContext: DbContext, IAccount {
   /* implementing interface
   */
  public Task<IEnumerable<AccountClass>> GetAccountClass() {
    return this.AccountClass.ToListAsync();
  }
}
```

Inject DbContext instance casting as interface in your controller:

```cs
   public AccountClassesController(IAccountClass accountClass)
    {
        _accountClass = accountClass;
    }

    // GET: api/AccountClasses
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<AccountClass>>> GetAccountClass()
    {
        return await this._accountClass.GetAccountClass();
    }
```

You must configure you dependency injection framework to inject a new ApplicationDbContext as IAccountClass.

Comment: so I'll have to do that for all the controllers

Comment: yes, this is a very common pattern.

Comment: oh but then have written lots of logic many controller just want to able to switch context between the two using same models for both one for postgresql and other for sql server

Comment: I didn't understand, can you explain better? Essentially, with EF you will use the same classes for any database compatible. What changes is the connection string details and additional libs in the project.

Comment: look I have implemented database connection for postgresql and sqlserver now for them each one creates a different type of migration in code first, so had to create two dbcontext, now I want to be able to switch between dbcontext when I using postgresql or sql server

Answer (score 1):

You can check this answer here [is it a good practice to pass an EF DbContext as delegate in services to attach all changes on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517663/is-it-a-good-practice-to-pass-an-ef-dbcontext-as-delegate-in-services-to-attach).
But if you application don't have any performance issues is fine even if you instance new context due EF is incredible fast managing and building it up.